# How to load a different video for Dark Mode

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I want to load a different video based on the light/dark mode?

I searched around, but only found how to do it for images.

```html
    <picture>
      <source 
        srcset="settings-dark.png"
        media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="settings-light.png"
        media="(prefers-color-scheme: light), (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)"
      />
      <img src="settings-light.png" id="screenshot" loading="lazy" />
    </picture>
```

I tried to apply the same logic for the video tag, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really unfortunate that `media` isn't supported on `source` elements inside of a `video` elements. This kind of leaves us needing to use multiple video tags (or javascript) like this:

```html
<style>
  .dark-video {
    display: none;
  }

  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .dark-video {
      display: block;
    }

    .light-video {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<video class="light-video" src="/light.mp4" />
<video class="dark-video" src="/dark.mp4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth noting that Safari supports the media 'prefers-color-scheme' parameter in the source tag. But you'd need a fallback for it for basically all over browsers. But if you are targeting mobile iOS directly, you can do it simply.

```html
<video autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="light-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="(prefers-color-scheme:light)">
  <source src="dark-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="(prefers-color-scheme:dark)">
</video>
```